# Principal Component Analysis in face recognition - python/java

Tags: java, python, computer-vision, face-recognition, pca

i want to perform facial recognition by using the Principal Component Analysis algorithm. I want to implement the algorithm in python or java myself however i am unsure where to start. Would appreciate some code samples/tutorials/references to get me started.

Comment: Since you mention PCA, you may also want to possibly post/check here: http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can start by reading the original paper about the EigenFaces
method (PCA-based face recognition):

"Eigenfaces for Recognition": http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~mturk/Papers/jcn.pdf

Also, if you want to find some code samples, OpenCV implemented
in of the latest versions, a face recognizer that is also based
on EigenFaces:

http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html?highlight=face%20recognition#createeigenfacerecognizer

Please notice that are python bindings for the OpenCV and that also
a Java version of OpenCV called JavaCV.

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to write your own PCA code, I suggest you look at the Wikipedia Article for a starting point.

If you are looking for PCA code, try using the one on [Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html).

For general PCA advice: typically, one would turn the 2D image-array into a 1-D byte array (by stacking).  If you do this for each of your n training images and assuming each one is p pixels when flattened, then you have your n x p training set for PCA!  (Note: there are a number of tricks with PCA, such as taking zero-meaning the data etc ...)

Also, there is an extensive literature that suggests [Non-negative Matrix Factorization is better for facial recognition](http://www.cvc.uab.es/~jordi/FinalCCIA2002.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple tutorial using python: http://www.janeriksolem.net/2009/01/pca-for-images-using-python.html